# Проход по пикселям изображения

Tags: php

Привет. Как я могу с помощью PHP взять изображение и пройтись по каждому пикселю? Ещё хотелось бы знать, можно ли проверять цвет каждого пикселя?
Какие для этого есть инструменты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Узнать цвет пикселя (0,0):

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("image.png");
$rgb = imagecolorat($im, 0, 0);

$colors = imagecolorsforindex($im, $rgb);

var_dump($colors);
?>
```

Мануал: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecolorat.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecolorsforindex.php

Answer (score 0):

Можно через [GD2](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.image.php) (как в соседнем ответе), а можно через [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php)

```
<?php 
$image = new Imagick('testimage.jpg'); 
$x = 1; 
$y = 1; 
$pixel = $image->getImagePixelColor($x, $y); 
?>
```